# How to access API response data?

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, curl

I am able to access the ESHA api to return food data. An example of the response is bellow. Previously to access the response I would have nested foreach loops, however, I don't know if that is the best method to get the singluar values from the response since attempting it gave me various errors. Is there some way that I can access the data as an object? or is there a method to get the data without multiple nested foreach loops? Not really used API's much so quite unsure of the best way to go about it. Any help is really appreciated!

API Response:

```
Array ( [query] => subway [total] => 215 [first_page] => /foods?query=subway [next_page] => /foods?query=subway&start=25 [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:de2ed6f4-0c4e-4b57-b251-0dd7cd969491 [description] => sandwich, turkey breast, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Poultry [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:b96ca582-2393-45b1-99c4-2e965137194c [description] => sandwich, oven roasted chicken, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Poultry [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:07fa8ed2-16f5-4eea-88cd-dbfda56bf7f4 [description] => sandwich, Italian B.M.T., with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:04d88d69-7ccd-4367-979e-92e927839ebf [description] => cookie, chocolate chip [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Desserts [1] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:d9a79bf4-fd7b-4de0-aac5-2d54f6e90afe [description] => sandwich, Subway Club, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Poultry [2] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [5] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:1a36c15e-5005-4f0a-9835-193b19a0847a [description] => sandwich, sweet onion chicken teriyaki, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Poultry [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [6] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:15f0d6c6-469c-40f8-b5b8-a7f137b89f20 [description] => sandwich, meatball marinara, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [7] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:53cc9b56-c4c2-40d6-a87e-5b5121fa7e5a [description] => cookie, chocolate chunk [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Desserts [1] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [8] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:72c4f636-bacc-448b-8afa-6317e2ee1f16 [description] => sandwich, Veggie Delight, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Vegetables [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [9] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:ef79a6be-9b59-42a3-b60e-1784b1171435 [description] => sandwich, turkey breast & black forest ham, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Poultry [2] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [10] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:2ebea6cc-942a-49b1-8a87-59083b7a50ba [description] => sandwich, steak & cheese, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Dairy Products & Subs [2] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [11] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:c429b0b4-44ac-48a1-a6b5-5c857d6e6f49 [description] => sandwich, tuna, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Fish & Seafood [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [12] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:61ed9f44-1828-4ff1-9c46-46850496ffb1 [description] => salad, oven roasted chicken breast, without dressing [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Gluten Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Poultry [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [13] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:baccc1a2-6e8d-42d8-b5dd-687b5359e728 [description] => bread, italian, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Vegan [2] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [14] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:e30e2553-2089-465a-9003-96a194582fe7 [description] => sauce, honey mustard, fat free [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:6954ef62-e196-4824-8b70-9de685d75b72 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Gluten Free [2] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Condiments & Sauces ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:6954ef62-e196-4824-8b70-9de685d75b72 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [15] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:a5696ff4-0079-41a8-b94f-a0773930f95a [description] => salad, Subway Club, Fresh Fit, without dressing [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Gluten Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Dishes & Prepared Foods [2] => Vegetables [3] => Poultry ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [16] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:1cd754c0-bd45-47d6-b3d9-a5a1a9aca3b5 [description] => cookie, oatmeal raisin [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Desserts [1] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [17] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:569b6ec9-a1f6-4f8c-829c-8c05a8feaa0e [description] => salad, Veggie Delight, Fresh Fit, without dressing [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Gluten Free [2] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Dishes & Prepared Foods [1] => Vegetables ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [18] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:56766390-6e9f-4d9e-90be-05a32f874336 [description] => sandwich, roast beef, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [19] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:2b48074e-0c07-44e8-b99e-6d1b4ec58f49 [description] => cookie, sugar [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Desserts [1] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [20] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:9369e7ff-8e94-4060-a842-30fcf714dc01 [description] => sandwich, black forest ham, with wheat, 6" [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Sandwiches ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [21] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:0a3a05fb-70b2-4a85-9fd3-1e6a20eb7f62 [description] => oil, olive blend [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:6954ef62-e196-4824-8b70-9de685d75b72 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Vegan [2] => Gluten Free [3] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Condiments & Sauces ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:6954ef62-e196-4824-8b70-9de685d75b72 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [22] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:a2f7ecda-f5f5-4089-af7e-6aa16d17590a [description] => cookie, white chip macadamia [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Desserts [1] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [23] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:e3431466-8e88-4584-a946-4d569e4a5df1 [description] => cookie, peanut butter [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Vegetarian/Lactovo ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Desserts [1] => Bread & Bakery ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) [24] => Array ( [id] => urn:uuid:5e35f65d-6bb3-4081-a1e2-d7745f93fe8f [description] => salad, black forest ham, without dressing [category] => Subway [quantity] => 1 [product] => Subway [supplier] => Subway [unit] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [characteristics] => Array ( [0] => Dairy Free [1] => Gluten Free ) [groups] => Array ( [0] => Meat [1] => Dishes & Prepared Foods [2] => Vegetables ) [units] => Array ( [0] => urn:uuid:85562e85-ba37-4e4a-8400-da43170204a7 [1] => urn:uuid:9eda6d41-4fbb-4a97-b046-46aee8a086de [2] => urn:uuid:e1d79375-15db-4ed7-8ead-f64dc2319091 [3] => urn:uuid:e0ad190a-d48b-443e-b637-e1cf05db2cdb [4] => urn:uuid:3e8384f0-ea47-4fde-b7e1-a12747b28a30 [5] => urn:uuid:d3be684c-ebfa-4861-924f-8840600d1e84 [6] => urn:uuid:0e5f4dd2-3353-477f-9773-0ed116c93e2e ) ) ) )
```

I know the output is not formatted well. I've tried to output it within `<pre>` tags however this did not work. If theres an easier way to view this data please let me know!

The code to return the data:

```
$get_data = callAPI('GET', 'https://nutrition-api.esha.com/foods?query=' . urlencode($\_POST\['prodInp'\]) . '&start=0&count=25&spell=true', false);
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($response) . "</pre>";
```

Thanks!!

I have tried using two nested foreach loops, but I couldn't seem to get it to work. I could be doing it wrong or overcomplicating it. I want to be able to access the [id] and [description] of each of the results so I can output them and have a user select which option they require.

Comment: FYI: `echo "<pre>" . print_r($response) . "</pre>";` does not work, because `print_r` writes directly to the output buffer. You what this effectively does, is write the dump to the buffer first, and then `<pre></pre>` _after_ that. You need to either use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($response); echo "</pre>";` - or the second parameter for print_r, which makes it _return_ its output, `echo "<pre>" . print_r($response, true) . "</pre>";`

Answer (score 0):

you can access the items from the response like that :

```
$response = json_decode($get_data,true);

$items = $response["items"] ?? [] ;

foreach ($items as $item ){
    echo "id :".  $item["id"] . "<br>";
    echo "description :".  $item["description"] . "<br>";
    echo "category :".  $item["category"] . "<br>";
    echo "quantity :".  $item["quantity"] . "<br>";
    echo "product :".  $item["product"] . "<br>";
    echo "supplier :".  $item["supplier"] . "<br>";
    echo "unit :".  $item["unit"] . "<br>";
    echo "characteristics :".  implode(",",$item["characteristics"]) . "<br>";
    echo "groups :".  implode(",",$item["groups"]) . "<br>";
    echo "units :".  implode(",",$item["units"]) . "<br>";
}
```